ElementorPro IsLicenseExpired not found issue
I have never use ElementorPro, but one client has webpage with it. Currently (admin) page gives following error (log and wp_debug) :

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "ElementorPro\Modules\Announcements\Triggers\IsLicenseExpired" not found in ...

What's going on:

if ElementorPro is enabled, public site works fine (and design is ok), but admin site produces that error and admin side is not accessible;
if ElementorPro is disabled, public site works more-or-less fine, some design issues and maybe usability (don't know) and admin side is also fine.

Google (and Elementor) do not have info about that error.
Does ANYBODY have some idea what that means?
ElementorPro licence expired?

"Does ANYBODY have some idea what that means? ElementorPro licence expired?" - no, it means that the class that is supposed to perform this check, whether the license is expired, wasn't found. Have you first of all verified, whether the corresponding folder contains a matching file? (Should be named is-license-expired.php)

Not even sure which folder the "is-license-expired.php" should be in. Announcements folder does not have T(t)riggers folder in it.

Even the basic version of Elementor has that folder, https://github.com/elementor/elementor/tree/main/modules/announcements/triggers - so I would assume, that the pro version is very likely to have it as well. If it is missing on the system in question, then probably someone did not upload all the necessary files?

Oh that's just great. Now I have to find pro files from somewhere to download. I'm afraid to remove the plugin to reinstall it.

@C3roe - thanks for your help! Found the missing folder and file and added it to correct place.
